# What is the error at else statement?

Tags: php

What is the problem in the code? When I try to run the code, I have problem in else part. Hope someone can help me to solve this part.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php

$first_name="William";
$last_name="Smitch";
$age="22";
$staus="";

if ($age>0 && $age<18);
    {
        $status="Under Age";
    }
    else
    {
        $status="Adult";
    }

function profile ($fnam,$lnam,$age)
{
    echo "My friend is ".$fnam." ".$lnam.", He is ".$age."year old";
}
echo "My name is ".$first_name." ".$last_name."<br>";
echo "I am ".$age." year old and i m an ".$status."<br>";
echo "Thank You<br>";
profile ("Frankie","Jones",20);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I am encountering: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\june2012_d.php on line 16`

Comment: OP, learn to tag your questions, it helps you and helps the site. Also, for the future, it helps to copy in any details you have of the error too.

Comment: You have a superfluous semicolon after the `if` statement, which means the following block is not related to the `if`, which in turn makes the `else` a surprise for the parser. `if ($age>0 && $age<18);` → `if ($age>0 && $age<18)`

Comment: FRANKIE please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks.

Comment: FRANKIE you marked my answer first then unmarked it, then said that you did it by mistake and after that no marking. Really frustrating. deleting my answer

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the `;` after your `if`-statement.

```
if ($age>0 && $age<18);
{
    $status="Under Age";
}
else
{
    $status="Adult";
}
```

It closes the `if` and thus it won't expect an `else`. Remove it and it will work.

*Hint*: $status and $staus are not the same variable ;-)